# Loading ajax content on reactable - reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

It looks pretty simple but I am stuck here. I just want to load the ajax content and render it in the table. I am able to render it using static content

```
class ObjectDataExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {appData: {}};

 }




    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://test.json')
            .then((result)=> {

                //const thisData = result.data;
                this.setState({appData: result.data});
            })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
    }



// Render your table
    render()
    {
            console.log(this.state.appData);
            //I can see the above console logs
        return (
            //this is not coming 
<Table className="react-listing-table table" data={this.state.appData} sortable={[
                    'Address',
                    'Suburb',
                    'Sale Date'
                ]}




                   defaultSort={{column: 'Sale Date', direction: 'asc'}}
                   defaultSortDescending>
//static content like below are rendered
                    <Tr className="react-listing-table table"
                        data={ [
                            {'Address':'address','Suburb':'suburb','Postc.':'2153','Sale Date':'21\/08\/17','Sale Price':'$640500','Comm':'$19200','LA':'($3545)','BA':'($2540)','Settelement':'12\/02\/2018'},
                            {'Address':'address','Suburb':'test','Postc.':'2153','Sale Date':'21\/08\/17','Sale Price':'$640500','Comm':'$19200','LA':'($3545)','BA':'TL($2540)','Settelement':'12\/02\/2018'},

                        ]} />



            </Table>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = ObjectDataExample;

window.WB.react.renderListingDataTable = function() {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ObjectDataExample/>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('listing-table-wrapper')
    );
}
```

I got the weird error **Uncaught TypeError: this.data.concat is not a function**

I AM  using https://github.com/glittershark/reactable

Comment: What happens when you set `<Table data={null}>`? Maybe this is an issue where you are passing null to the component when it does not expect null. If so I would change your render method to render `<Table>` only when `this.state.data !== null`.

Comment: @H Le I dont think that is an issue, when I pass null the blank table is coming up without any error.

Comment: Are you sure that `result.data` is an array?

Comment: result.data is an object

Comment: how are you adding it to the data prop?

Comment: data prop should be an array I think so it can iterate

Comment: let me try  this

Comment: Fairly certain that it is a problem with the data coming back from your ajax request.
Maybe it's json and you need to deserialize it? `<Table data={JSON.parse(this.state.appData)}/>`

Comment: @bennygenel : My bad it is object but I declared it as array . I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Folks It was stupid mistake from my side , I declared array instead of object

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {appData: []}; //previously it was appdata:{}


 }
```

Thanks @bennygenal for pointing it out